# Set tooltip max width style

Tags: c#, xml, wpf, datagrid

Ok, i know my question might be super dumb- but i couldn't find the solution my self- so here i am- asking your help:

in `wpf` i have a `DataGrid` with different styles.

now, i need to set the tooltip max width.

this is my `DataGridCell` style:

```
<Style TargetType="DataGridCell" x:Key="MyDataGridCellStyle">
            <EventSetter Event="PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" Handler="DataGridCell_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" />
            <EventSetter Event="PreviewTextInput" Handler="DataGridCell_PreviewTextInput" />
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14" />
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="White" />
            <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Arial" />
            <Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate" Value="{x:Null}"/>
            <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self},Path=Content.Text}"/>
        </Style>
```

how do i add to the tooltip the max width style?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this please

Keep this code

```
<Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self},Path=Content.Text}"/>
```

and add this to your datagrid

```
<DataGrid.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="ToolTip">
                <Setter Property="MaxWidth" Value="20" />
                <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"  >
                                <ContentPresenter.Resources>
                                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                                        <Setter Property="TextWrapping" Value="Wrap" />
                                    </Style>
                                </ContentPresenter.Resources>
                            </ContentPresenter>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </DataGrid.Resources>
```

Comment: instead of putting the style under the DataGrid.Resources i just putted it in the app.xaml. tnx!

Answer (score -1):

Is what you tried to put your tooltip in a textblock

```
    <Setter Property="ToolTip">
       <Setter.Value>
           <TextBlock MaxWidth="..." TextWrapping="Wrap"  Text ="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self},Path=Content.Text}"/>
       </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
```

Comment: I have not paid attention, it's logical , try to change binding from self (Textblock) to dtatgridcell

Comment: I have tried another solution try to add this into datagrid and keep tooltip like first code

Comment: but i want the style to be in the app.xaml